# Why does my Layout of the carousel render vertically while flexed?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have an carousel set up for view of store products.

Here you can test the code out here in the demo snippet [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/BlockStrt/meed/main?workspaceId=9b24eacc-ff1b-4a22-b17d-d8a063f3a2c5&file=%2Fpages%2Fstore.js&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522cle4octh7000xftgl2p5u5eef%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522spaces%2522%253A%257B%2522cle4ocvf10015356gb0xfo5yx%2522%253A%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522cle4ocvf10015356gb0xfo5yx%2522%252C%2522name%2522%253A%2522Default%2522%252C%2522devtools%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522cle4odk7g00ce356g8ldfpgfv%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522SETUP_SHELL_LOG%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522cle4octxv001kftgl71o8fb4y%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522cle4octxv001kftgl71o8fb4y%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522cle4ocvf20016356gldy92dq5%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PROJECT_SETUP%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522cle4odhvr0095356glqb4p81d%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522currentSpace%2522%253A%2522cle4ocvf10015356gb0xfo5yx%2522%252C%2522spacesOrder%2522%253A%255B%2522cle4ocvf10015356gb0xfo5yx%2522%255D%252C%2522hideCodeEditor%2522%253Afalse%257D)

Mapping through my array of images it renders vertically on the screen when they should over lap each other given the view of a carousel to click from left to right. The container is relative to its position, flexed with 0 inset. I don't understand how the images render vertically

```
export default function Storetwo(){
    const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(0);
    const [currentProduct, setCurrentProduct] = useState(slides[0]);
    const { handleSubmit, reset, setValue, control } = useForm({ defaultValues });
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);

    const handlePreviousClick = () => {
        setCurrentSlide(currentSlide === 0 ? slides.length - 1 : currentSlide - 1);
        setCurrentProduct(slides[currentSlide]);
    }
    const handleNextClick = () => {
        setCurrentSlide(currentSlide === slides.length - 1 ? 0 : currentSlide + 1);
        setCurrentProduct(slides[currentSlide]);
    }
    return(
<div className=' md:flex  p-2 h-[100vh]  '>
          {/* image container */}          
    <div className=" w-[100%] md:w-[100%] ">
            {slides.map((slide, index) => (
                <div key={index} className={`relative flex inset-0 z-10 justify-center items-center ${index === currentSlide ? 'block' : 'hidden'}`}>           
                <Image src={slide.image} width={200} height={200} key={index} alt="" className="object-cover p-10   " />
                <div className=" top-40 left-10 justify-center items-center mx-auto flex ">
                <button className='text-3xl ' onClick={handlePreviousClick}><ArrowBackIosIcon/></button>
                <button className='text-3xl ' onClick={handleNextClick}><ArrowForwardIosIcon /></button>
                </div>
          </div>
      ))}
    </div>
      .../
```

Here are the vertical rendering images
[image: Images rendering vertical]

Comment: **Don't add tags.** [ask] covers that.

Answer (score 0):

Your link is broken, which is one of the reasons why external live examples aren't recommended on StackOverflow. [Use Snippets instead](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

As for your question, I believe you're misunderstanding how flexbox works (or maybe it's just an oversight).

You're applying `flex` to the divs that are being rendered as a result of your mapping, when you should be adding it to their *container* instead. It's the container that will set its children position as flexbox. Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox_container.asp).

```js
    [...]
    return(
    <div className=' md:flex  p-2 h-[100vh]  '>
          {/* image container */}          
    <div className="flex w-[100%] md:w-[100%] "> {/* <= here */}
            {slides.map((slide, index) => (
                <div key={index} className={`relative flex inset-0 z-10 justify-center items-center ${index === currentSlide ? 'block' : 'hidden'}`}>           
                <Image src={slide.image} width={200} height={200} key={index} alt="" className="object-cover p-10   " />
                <div className=" top-40 left-10 justify-center items-center mx-auto flex ">
                <button className='text-3xl ' onClick={handlePreviousClick}><ArrowBackIosIcon/></button>
                <button className='text-3xl ' onClick={handleNextClick}><ArrowForwardIosIcon /></button>
                </div>
          </div>
      ))}
    </div>
```